# Ownership of Eclipse icons in EMF Autogenerated code

Tags: copyright

This is regarding the Eclipse Icons which are part of the code generated using Eclipse Modelling Framework (EMF). These Eclipse Icons are not part of the input model provided by the developer, but is inserted by the EMF blueprint. Mr. Ed Merks (developer of EMF) has already clarified here (http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t116081.html) that EPL terms would not be applicable to code generated by EMF. The confusion is regarding the Eclipse icons which are part of such auto-generated code. These Icons can be downloaded from the Eclipse Icons repository and is licensed under the EPL. Could anyone provide clarification regarding the ownership of such Eclipse icons which are part of EMF auto-generated code.

Answer (score 1):

If the icons are originally under the EPL the fact that they are further included in some generated EMF package does not change their license and the icons would stay under the EPL. Exactly in the same way that if your EMF model is used generate some code, the license of the code is that from your EMF model and not that of the EMF code generator itself.